# perl support IPv6 address format [::1] in HTTP::Request

Tags: perl, http, ipv6

Debian Wheezy (perl 5.14)

**Work nice:**

```
use LWP::Simple;
print get( 'http://ip6-localhost:80' );
```

**Not working** (1)

```
use LWP::Simple;
print get( 'http://[::1]:80' );
```

**Not working** (2) [Return: **Bad hostname**]

```
use LWP::Simple;
$ua = new LWP::UserAgent();
my $req = new HTTP::Request("GET", "http://[::1]/");
my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

**Not working** (3) [Return: **Connection refused**]

```
use Net::INET6Glue::INET_is_INET6;
use LWP::Simple;
$ua = new LWP::UserAgent();
my $req = new HTTP::Request("GET", "http://[::1]/");
my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

Why I need it? Because ldirectord need it. :(
Any suggestion?

Comment: This looks more like a bug report or feature request. Have you tried raising it with the CPAN distributions in question?

Comment: I don't try report on CPAN, because my understanding of where(library/module/libc/..) is problem is low. :(
But, i will try it. Wait moment. First step : install last version(5.16).

Comment: perlbug used and bug reported as high priority

Comment: Use the "Bugs" link on the CPAN page of the module concerned. For example http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/ points at https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=libwww-perl wherein you'll find a number of existing IPv6-related bugs already.

Answer (score 1):

Another post suggested using  [INET6Glue](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/Net-INET6Glue-0.5/lib/Net/INET6Glue/INET_is_INET6.pm)

```
use Net::INET6Glue::INET_is_INET6;
use LWP::Simple;
print get( 'http://[::1]:80' );
print get( 'http://ipv6.google.com' );
```